# How can I find the sessionState ticket?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In web.config there is a parameter:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="50"/>
</authentication>
```

I can find how long is left by this code:

```
   if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)Page.User.Identity;
      FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;
   }
```

And in web.config there is:

```
<sessionState timeout="50"/>
```

can I find the ticket of the sessionState period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programatically find the session timeout from any code behind file with

```
int timeout = Session.Timeout;
```

or from inside a class with

```
int timeout = HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout;
```